# How to edit an image in laravel 5 if user upload a new one ,otherwise upload with old image file

Tags: image-processing, laravel-5.1

I have an edit form which has an image field where a user can upload a new image if he wants to.

But if the user does not upload a new photo I  want to just use the photo that's already in the database. And not update the image field at all. But in my code whenever I am trying to without uploading new image form is not taking the old input value.

Here is my edit function:

```
public function expenseupdate1(){

        $input = Input::only('id','Expense_date','Expense_category_id','Vendor_id','Customer_id','Amount','Tax1_id','Tax2_id','Note','Receipt'); 


        $data=new Expense;

        $id=$input['id'];
        $Expense_date=$input['Expense_date'];
        $Expense_category_id=$input['Expense_category_id'];
        $Vendor_id=$input['Vendor_id'];
        $Customer_id=$input['Customer_id'];
        $Amount=$input['Amount'];
        $Tax1_id=$input['Tax1_id'];
        $Tax2_id=$input['Tax2_id'];
        $Note=$input['Note'];

        if(Input::hasFile('Receipt')) {

                $file = Input::file('Receipt');

                $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $data->Receipt = $name;
                $file->move(public_path() . '/images/', $name);         


            }            

    $affectedrows=Expense::where('id', '=', $id)->update(array('Expense_date' => $Expense_date,'Expense_category_id'=>$Expense_category_id,'Vendor_id'=>$Vendor_id,'Customer_id'=>$Customer_id,'Amount'=>$Amount,'Tax1_id'=>$Tax1_id,'Tax2_id'=>$Tax2_id,'Note'=>$Note,'Receipt'=>$Receipt));

       return redirect('expenseinfo');

   }
```

and here is my update form image field code:

```
<td> <div class="form-group"style="margin-left:-305px">
            {!! Form::label('image', 'Receipt') !!}

            <input  Input::old('Receipt'), type="file" name="Receipt" value = '{{$data->Receipt}}'></td><td><?php echo $data->Receipt; ?></td>
        </div></td>
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::submit('Update', array( 'class'=>'' )) !!}


        {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: Is `Expense` an Eloquent model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't set a default value for file.

> The file input type creates a field
>   through which users can upload files
>   from their local computer or network.
>   The VALUE attribute specifies the name
>   of the initial file, but it is
>   typically ignored by browsers as a
>   security precaution.

So, your application is behaving correctly. Since the image is already in the database you wouldn't need to uploaded it again.

Also, just FYI but you can clean up your controller method dramatically!

```
/**                                                                                                                                                     
 * Update Expense 1                                                                                                                                     
 *                                                                                                                                                      
 * @param Request $request                                                                                                                              
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector                                                                             
 */                                                                                                                                                     
public function expenseupdate1(Request $request){                                                                                                       

    $expense = Expense::find($request->input('id'));                                                                                                    
    $expense->fill($request->only('id','Expense_date','Expense_category_id','Vendor_id','Customer_id','Amount','Tax1_id','Tax2_id','Note','Receipt'));  

    if($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {                                                                                                                  

        $file = $request->file('Receipt');                                                                                                              

        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();                                                                                          
        $expense->Receipt = $name;                                                                                                                      
        $file->move(public_path('/images/'), $name);                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                   

    $expense->save();                                                                                                                                   

    return redirect('expenseinfo');                                                                                                                     
}
```

The above assumes you have the necessary `use` statements at the top of you're controller i.e.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Expense; //Assuming that Expense is in this namespace
```

If you haven't already, you should set the fillable array for you model to allow the `fill()` method (mass assignment) to work http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

There is even more you can do but I have already gone outside the scope of this question. I would, however, suggest looking at:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)